# Getting `Store error: the application attempted to write an object with no provided typename but the store already contains an object with typename`

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-cache-inmemory

I am getting Store Error when updating and am new to apollo and graphQL so unable to understand what am i doing wrong.
I am trying to update the first name and last name of a person. 
This object is nested and i am passing typeName as that of the wrapped object.
If anyone understands this and can suggest please let me know

This is how it looks like in apollo:

> validationType:age@empId
>
> > persondetails: personDetailsType
> >
> > > first: "abc" 
> > >          empId: 10002 
> > >          age: "21" 
> > >          last: "def"

Values are being passed from here:

```
 <Button content="Save"
              onClick={(_, {value}) => {
                this.props.mutation({
                  variables: {
                    persondetails: {
                      first: this.state.first,
                      last: this.state.last,
                      empId: empId,
                      age: age
                    },
                      age,
                      empId,
                  }
                });
              }}
            />
```

My Update query looks something like this:

```
updatePersonDetails: (
      _,
      {persondetails, age, empId},
      {cache}
    ) => {
      cache.writeFragment({
        id: `validationType:${age}!${empId}`,
        fragment: gql`
          fragment updatePersonDetails on validationType {
            persondetails {
              first
              last
              age
              empId
              __typename

            }
            __typename
          }
        `,
        data: {
          persondetails: persondetails,
          age,
          empId,
          __typename: 'validationType'
        }
      });
```

### I get below error when updating:

```
[Network error]: Error: Error writing result to store for query:
 {
  ...updatePersonDetails
}

fragment persondetails on validationType {
  persondetails {
   first
   last
   age
   empId
    __typename
  }
  __typename
}

Store error: the application attempted to write an object with no provided typename but the store already contains an object with typename of personDetailsType for the object of id $validationType!21.1002. The selectionSet that was trying to be written is:
persondetails {
 first
 last
 age
 empId
  __typename
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the `persondetails` inside of `data` is missing the `__typename`. Hard to tell for sure though since your code doesn't show how the `updatePersonDetails` function is being called

Comment: It for sure has something to do with typename but I do have a __typename within data field, which makes it difficult to understand.
In the button tag, onClick --> it calls the props.mutation which in turn calls the update method. Below code gives more clarity : 

`export default MutationHoC({
  Component: PersonDetailsEditComponent,
  mutation: updatePersonDetails
});`

Comment: I can see data being reflected in cache but i guess on retrieving or doing some more operations it fails and throws this error.

Comment: `__typename` is a meta field that Apollo attaches automatically in order to easily [normalize query results in the cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#normalization). When using `writeData` or `writeFragment`, every object inside of `data` should have the appropriate `__typename` field. If it's missing, you'll encounter issues when fetching things from the cache.

Comment: So my question is: does the `persondetails` object you're using inside of the `updatePersonDetails` function contain `__typename`. If not, then that's what's likely causing the error. But, again, it's hard to ascertain that without seeing more of the code.

Comment: I see. Yeah i have it within `persondetails` object.

Answer (score 1):

I was having my object declared in wrong way in resolvers when passing in update. And also i was missing typeName within that object.
The correct syntax was:

```
updatePersonDetails: (
      _,
      {persondetails, age, empId},
      {cache}
    ) => {
      cache.writeFragment({
        id: `validationType:${age}!${empId}`,
        fragment: gql`
          fragment updatePersonDetails on validationType {
            persondetails {
              first
              last
              age
              empId
              __typename

            }
            __typename
          }
        `,
        data: {
          persondetails: {
           ...persondetails,
           __typename: 'persondetailsType'
}
          __typename: 'validationType'
        }
      });
```